# How to read from .txt in C

Tags: c, arrays, fopen

I have to read from a .txt like this (1. - txt line)

1. 1 2
2. 1 2 3
3. 1 3 4

but I have to read like: "1" first line, attribute to `x[0]`, "2" first line attribute to `x[1]`. I know how to do that but the problem is that I have to skip to the line 2 and do the same, but it doesn't work.
So It'd be like
`x[2]=1. x[2]=2, x[3]=3, x[4]=1, x[5]=3, x[6]=4`
Is there a way for me to do it???
Thanks!

---

Let me try to be more especific

1. 1 2 1
2. 2 3 1
3. 3 4

Imagine this is a txt file where 3. 2. and 1. are first, second and third line. I have to read each number on each line and assign to a `vet[MAX]`;
I can do it, but only with the first line. I don't know how to skip to the second one

---

My code

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
char buf[1024];
int numeros[8];

FILE *fp = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
if(fp == NULL)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) {
    if(buf[0] == '\n')
        continue;

    sscanf(buf, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &numeros[0], &numeros[1], &numeros[2], &numeros[3],&numeros[4], &numeros[5], &numeros[6]);
}

fclose(fp);
    printf(" \n %d \n %d \n %d \n %d \n %d \n %d \n %d", numeros[0], numeros[1], numeros[2], numeros[3],numeros[4], numeros[5], numeros[6]);
```

}

```
   the output
```

3
 4
 1
 131072
 2685712
 302692880
 4798692
Process returned 53 (0x35)   execution time : 0.016 s
Press any key to continue.

And I wanted

1 2 2 1 2 3 1 3 4

Comment: How can you put two different values in `x[2]`?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You should show us some code.

Comment: Could you please explain your issue a bit more clearly. I read your question 3 times now and I still don't understand completely what you try to accomplish.

Comment: could you please share your code snippet ?

Comment: can you please tell what output you want with above input ?and please share your code

Comment: I am still not getting what you really want , can you please explain it little bit more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the result of `sscanf()`.

You will likely get 2 or 3 each loop.  This means 2 or 3 `int` were successfully scanned.  This number can then be used to determine saving the `int` in `numeros[]`.

```
int i=0;
while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) {
  int t[7];
  int result = sscanf(buf, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &t[0], &t[1], &t[2], &t[3], &t[4], &t[5], &t[6]);
  if (result <= 0) break;  // EOF, IO error, bad data
  for (int r=0; r<result; r++) {
    if (i >= sizeof(numeros)/sizeof(numeros[0[)) break;  // too many
    numeros[i++] = t[r];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your double use of `x[2]` is a typo, and assuming the line numbers are not really in the file, all you need is to loop doing:

```
fscanf(file, "%d", &x[i++]);
```

until it fails. So remember the check the return value, if it isn't 1 it failed to find a number to convert and store, and you should stop.

Of course, this assumes that `x` has space enough, and that `i` is initialized to 0.